# Display related data Yii 1

Tags: php, yii

I have this in my model:

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
                'role' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'MedRoles', 'role_id'),
        );
    }
```

Also I have this in my controller:

```
public function actionIndex() {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->join = "LEFT JOIN med_roles r ON r.id = t.role_id";
        $criteria->order = "id DESC";
        $userData = MedUsers::model()->findAll($criteria);
        $this->render('index', array(
            'users' => $userData
        ));
    }
```

And my DB has tables: med_users and med_roles
I have no problem showing data from med_users, but **cannot display data from related med_roles. How do I do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$userData = MedUsers::model()->with('role')->findAll($criteria);

foreach($userData as $user) {
    echo $user->role->name;
}
```